# Drawing Elliptical Arc in tikz or tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf

**How to draw Elliptical Arc in tikz or tkz-euclide**

[image]

If we know center, X-Radius, Y-Radius , Start Angle - the start angle of the arc and End Angle - the end angle of the arc

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{ \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }

\tikzset{elliparc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{%
insert path={(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=0]
\draw[dashed] (0,0) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw[] (0,0) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];

\draw[dashed] (0,3) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw[] (0,3) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];% not working

%\draw (0,3) ellipse ({1cm} and {0.5cm});

\draw[] (1,0) -- ++(0,3);
\draw[] (-1,0) -- ++(0,3);

\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {$r$} ++(1,0);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) --  ++(0,3.05);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above,sloped] {$h$} ++(0,3.05);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here?

Comment: \draw[] (0,0) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm]; Works well...\draw[] (0,3) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];% not working (Center of ellipse changed)

Comment: isn't `\tikz\draw (3,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=80, x radius=3, y radius=1];` ?

Comment: @touhami  (3,0) is starting point  of the arc. But i have center and not starting point...

Comment: @sandu Try `\draw (3,0) ++ ({3*cos(80)},{1*sin(80)}) arc (80:180:3 and 1);` for an arc with center at `(3,0)`, start angle of `80`, end angle of `180`, x radius of `3` and y radius of `1`. Compare with `\draw[dashed,gray] (3,0) circle (3 and 1);` to see the complete ellipse.

Comment: @Max You are right but there is already a command `\centerarc` defined in the code. This does what you suggest, doesn't it?

Comment: @marmot Ah now I see. The solution is to change `\tikzset{elliparc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{insert path={(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}}}` to `\tikzset{elliparc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{insert path={++(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}}}`. Notice the `++` at the start of `insert path`, which indicates that you use the last point as reference position.

Comment: @Max Perhaps you should post an answer... (I was stumbling over the fact that `\centerarc` was defined but not used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this simply by adding `++` to the first coordinate in the `insert path` key of `elliparc`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\tikzset{elliparc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{%
insert path={++(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=0]
\draw[dashed] (0,0) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw (0,0) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];

\draw[dashed] (0,3) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw (0,3) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];% working

\draw (1,0) -- ++(0,3);
\draw (-1,0) -- ++(0,3);

\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {$r$} ++(1,0);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) -- ++(0,3.05);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above,sloped] {$h$} ++(0,3.05);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just for fun I also edited your definition of `\centerarc` such that the optional first argument is really optional, and it does not need the `calc` library anymore, because that seemed a bit overkill.

```
\makeatletter
\def\centerarci[#1](#2) (#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{\draw[#1] (#2) ++(#3:#5) arc (#3:#4:#5);}
\def\centerarc{\@ifnextchar[{\centerarci}{\centerarci[]}}
\makeatother
```

MWE with `\centerarc` and drawing the cylinder with both options:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\def\centerarci[#1](#2) (#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{\draw[#1] (#2) ++(#3:#5) arc (#3:#4:#5);}
\def\centerarc{\@ifnextchar[{\centerarci}{\centerarci[]}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{elliparc/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{%
insert path={++(#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=0]
\draw[dashed] (0,0) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw (0,0) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];

\draw[dashed] (0,3) [elliparc=0:180:1cm and .5cm];
\draw (0,3) [elliparc=-180:0:1cm and .5cm];% working

\draw (1,0) -- ++(0,3);
\draw (-1,0) -- ++(0,3);

\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {$r$} ++(1,0);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) --  ++(0,3.05);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above,sloped] {$h$} ++(0,3.05);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=0]
\centerarc[dashed](0,0) (0:180:1cm and 0.5cm);
\centerarc(0,0) (-180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);

\centerarc[dashed](0,3) (0:180:1cm and 0.5cm);
\centerarc(0,3)  (-180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);

\draw (1,0) -- ++(0,3);
\draw (-1,0) -- ++(0,3);

\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {$r$} ++(1,0);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) --  ++(0,3.05);
\draw[thin,color=brown] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\path (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,above,sloped] {$h$} ++(0,3.05);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```